# Factorize in a particular way

Tags: simplifying-expressions, factorization

I was trying to factorise this polynomial expression:

```
TestPolynomial=-p1^2 x1 x2 - p3^2 x1 x3 - p1^2 x2 x3 + 2 p1 p3 x2 x3 - p3^2 x2 x3
```

into this form,

```
-p1^2 x1 x2 - p3^2 x1 x3 - (p1-p3)^2 x2 x3
```

However, when we use `Simplify[]`, we obtain

```
2 p1 p3 x2 x3 - p3^2 (x1 + x2) x3 - p1^2 x2 (x1 + x3)
```

How can I say Mathematica that I wish to get the polynomial factorised in terms of variables (p1,p3).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
xvars={x1,x2,x3};
FromCoefficientRules[CoefficientRules[TestPolynomial,xvars]//Factor,xvars]
```

This is based on the following interpretation of your question: View the expression as a polynomial in `x1`, `x2`, `x3` with coefficients that are polynomials in `p1`, `p2`, `p3` and simplify those coefficients. I use `CoefficientRules` since that is a very useful command in many situations.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to do that is:

```
Collect[TestPolynomial,{x1,x2,x3},Simplify]
```

An inconvenience with the above code is that it also factorizes some of the variables :

output : `-(p1 - p3)^2 x2 x3 + x1 (-p1^2 x2 - p3^2 x3)`

If you prefer that the code only simplifies the coefficients, a solution is to take a symbol without an assigned value, say g, then enter the code (see footnote *tip below for a tip):

```
Expand@Collect[TestPolynomial,{x1,x2,x3},g@*Simplify] /.g->Identity
```

If you are looking for speed, at least for the example you gave, the code above is about 3 times faster than the one provided by @user293787 on my computer.

*tip: to be sure that the symbol will not be assigned a value in the future, you can use

```
\[FormalG]
```

(type the Esc key then the $ key or . key then g (or another letter) then the Esc key again ).

`\[FormalG]` is protected by default so it will not be assigned a value (maybe unless someone uses Unprotect but I have personally avoided using Unprotect)